# Slim framework - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

There is probably a very simple solution to this but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm working a Slim Project which was working fine.  I just did a fresh install of Yosemite on my system. I have installed MySQL and enabled PHP (5.5.20).  I moved my Slim project under `localhost/~username/apiproject`.

I get a '500 Internal Server Error' when I try to access my project. I have tried putting a simple html file in the same folder and accessing it via the browser and still get the same error on the HTML file. This tells me that the browser isn't able to access this folder.

Next I tried removing the `.htaccess` file from the root of the project.  When I did that, I was able to access the HTML page which I placed in the folder.  However, I am not able to access the project.

I'm assuming this has to be related to my Apache setting or my .htaccess file.  I have also enabled `mod_rewrite` in my Apache settings.  Here is what is in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase localhost/~username/apiproject
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have a look in your Apache error logs, to see what the error actually is.

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really a simple solution. RewriteBase must begin with a slash (/).
It must be the part of the url after the document root. In this case, I suppose it should be

```
RewriteBase /apiproject/
```

If your document root is /localhost, then RewriteBase must be /~username/apiproject/, but the first slash can not be absent.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in PHP 5.5.12, and the solution is to uncomment the following line in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows and you use wampserver then:

- Click on wampserver icon at the bottom, right
- Select Apache
- Select Apache modules
- Click on rewrite_module
- Wait for a minute for wampserver restarting
- Let's code and enjoy using slim framework API